# Multigroup multinomial logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution

I am using multinomial logistic regression (nnet package in R) to predict a categorical outcome (four categories) with three independent variables.

As my data come from different countries, instead of using a pooled sample, I would like to run multi-group multinomial logistic regression and check if the effects are different across countries.

Is it possible to run multi-group multinomial logistic regression in R? I know this is possible in MPlus, but I was not successful in finding a way to do it in R. Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with using `country` as a factor, and also use interactions with `country`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, I was just curious if there is a package that does multi-group analysis in R. Multi-group analysis requires less calculations (especially in multinom.log.reg. when there are several continuous and a categorical predictor), as the output provides effects of all predictors in each country. Although these could be calculated from the model where country is introduced as a predictor together with interactions (single-group model), I find it more convenient to have these effects immediately. The same goes for testing if effects of a predictor are different across countries.

Comment: Do you have a definition of/link/reference for your meaning of *multigroup analysis*?

Comment: Here an article comparing single-group and multi-group mediation models: Ryu, Ehri and Jeewon Cheong (2017), “Comparing Indirect Effects in Different Groups in Single-Group and Multi-Group Structural Equation Models,” Frontiers in Psychology, 8, 747. doi:10.3389/fpsyg.2017.00747